# Accessing SDK Wizard/installing additional drivers in MCUXpresso after initial project creation

Tags: eclipse, embedded, driver, nxp-microcontroller

Is there a way to re-access the SDK Wizard after the initial time you configure a project? Basically, at that point it lets you select which drivers you want and includes them in a drivers folder. However, as time went on I found that I need to add more drivers than I originally planned for. How do I select additional drivers to incorporate from the SDK after initial project creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it the information at the following link, in "add/remove components":
https://mcuoneclipse.com/2017/11/25/eclipse-mcuxpresso-ide-10-1-with-integrated-mcuxpresso-configuration-tools/

If the link breaks -
In the Project window view, there is a small icon that looks like a yellow square with perpendicular lines through it.

Click on the project so it is highlighted, then you will be able to click the square icon which says "Manage SDK Components" if you hover over it.

Once you click that, you can select/deselect components you wish to add/remove, respectively.